# Как вывести стандартную галерею WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery

У меня есть главная страница, на которой я вывожу все записи с названием и описанием. Внутри каждой записи есть стандартная галерея изображения - [gallery size="medium" ids="201,200,186,202,185"] . Мне нужно вывести галерею каждой записи на главной странице... Как это сделать? Буду благодарен за помощь.